# Fastest way to transfer data over USB from Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense

Tags: arduino, serial-port, usb, nrf52, arduino-nano

I used the following test code to measure the time required for sending a single byte across USB using Arduino's Serial.write() method. The oscilloscope measured 85 us for sending a single byte.

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "nrf_delay.h"
#include "nrf_gpio.h"

#define OUTPUT_PIN NRF_GPIO_PIN_MAP(1,11)

const byte PRINT_BYTE = 254;

uint32_t startClock;
uint32_t stopClock;
uint32_t arithmeticMinuend = 4294967295;
uint32_t arithmeticSubtrahend = 2147483648;
uint32_t arithmeticDifference = 0;
uint32_t timeDifference1 = 0;
uint32_t timeDifference2 = 0;

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  while (!Serial);
  delay(1000);

  nrf_gpio_cfg_output(OUTPUT_PIN);
  us_ticker_init();
  startClock = us_ticker_read();
  stopClock = us_ticker_read();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Starting program:");
  timeDifference1 = microsecondsToSubtract2LongsOnce();
  timeDifference2 = microsecondsToSubtract2LongsAndPrint();
  us_ticker_free();
  Serial.print("timeDifference1 = ");
  Serial.print(timeDifference1);
  Serial.print(" us.\ntimeDifference2 = ");
  Serial.print(timeDifference2);
  Serial.println(" us.");

  us_ticker_init();
  microsecondsToSubtract2LongsOnceMeasuredWithScope();
  us_ticker_free();
  delay(10);
  us_ticker_init();
  microsecondsToSubtract2LongsTwiceMeasuredWithScope();
  us_ticker_free();
  delay(10);
  us_ticker_init();
  microsecondsToToggleOutputPinMeasuredWithScope();
  us_ticker_free();
  
  while(1) {
    
  }
}

//Prints 0-1 us:
uint32_t microsecondsToSubtract2LongsOnce() {
  startClock = us_ticker_read();
  stopClock = us_ticker_read();
  return stopClock - startClock;
}

//Prints 406 us:
uint32_t microsecondsToSubtract2LongsAndPrint() {
  startClock = us_ticker_read();
  Serial.write(PRINT_BYTE);
  stopClock = us_ticker_read();
  return stopClock - startClock;
}

//Measured 1.8 us on scope:
void microsecondsToSubtract2LongsOnceMeasuredWithScope() {
  nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(OUTPUT_PIN);
  startClock = us_ticker_read();
  stopClock = us_ticker_read();
  nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(OUTPUT_PIN);
}

//Measured 85 us on scope:
void microsecondsToSubtract2LongsTwiceMeasuredWithScope() {
  nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(OUTPUT_PIN);
  startClock = us_ticker_read();
  Serial.write(PRINT_BYTE);
  stopClock = us_ticker_read();
  nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(OUTPUT_PIN);
}

//Measured 500 ns on scope:
void microsecondsToToggleOutputPinMeasuredWithScope() {
  nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(OUTPUT_PIN);
  nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(OUTPUT_PIN);
}
```

I would like to be able to send all the sensor data in parallel over USB so I will need to be able to transfer MUCH faster than this! Anyone have any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase the transmission speed of a `Serial` communication you have to increase the baud rate value in the `Serial.begin()`.
[Here](https://lucidar.me/en/serialib/most-used-baud-rates-table/) you can find a table with baud rate and speed.

In your case the baud rate at 115200 corresponds of a byte duration of 86us the value you have measured.

According to Nordic's [documentation](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fps_nrf52840%2Fuart.html&cp=4_0_0_5_32_9_22&anchor=register.BAUDRATE), the nrf52840 supports baud rate until 1M

Comment: Changing the baud rate that way has no impact on the Nano 33 BLE sense. It uses USB natively so the COM port is virtual. Refer here for more details: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/slow-serial-on-nano-33-ble/673958/2

Comment: You are right. New idea: use the `Serial1` (is an hardware serial and should accept higher baud rates) connecting the TX and RX pins to a TTL UART-USB converter (an example [link](https://www.amazon.it/USB-TTL-232-485-modulo-convertitore-seriale/dp/B01LY97ZM5)) . Let me know if works.